# How can I exclude CSS from mobile devices

Tags: iphone, mobile, hover, css-sprites

I have some CSS sprites on the main page of my site. A different image appears when you hover over the element.

This works fine in a normal desktop, however on a mobile device (specifically an iPhone or iPad) the elements for the hover state appear stacked below the default image.

Is there a way I can say, only apply the hover in a non-desktop device.

I was looking over the max-device-width properties for the media queries, but it didn't exactly do what I wanted. Eg: What if a desktop browser resizes the window, then the hovers wont work.

```
<style media="screen">
#main{
 width: 985px;
 height: 1078px;
 background: url(../images/main.jpg);
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

#main li {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 list-style: none;
}

#mainSection1 a { left: 642px; width: 193px; top: 282px; height: 18px; position: absolute; }
#mainSection1 a:hover { background: url(../images/main.jpg) -642px -1360px; }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the browser window size shouldn't trigger CSS guarded by conditions of max/min-device-width. It will trigger CSS guarded with max/min-width though. Your screen resolution, however, may trigger your device-width sections.

But that won't be your only issue. It's that the logical px unit in CSS doesn't always map to the physical pixel count. If you are setting the initial-scale to 1 in the viewport meta tag, on 800x480 android phones and iphone4 the things may look bigger than they ought to.

You can use device-pixel-ratio in your media query to isolate these devices. I think the iphone4 device-pixel-ratio is 2.

I know none of the above by themselves provide you with a direct solution, but you can try to combine them to find out what works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll flag this as correct. I actually did some more debugging and worked out it wasn't the hover, but rather the list not scaling to size. I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657567/css-elements-with-sprites-on-iphone-ipad-not-scaling-correctly