# CSS elements (with sprites) on iPhone/iPad not scaling correctly

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, scale, css-sprites

I have a list on my main page which each has a link. Each list item has a different height and width which act like blocks on the page. Inside each list item is a link to another area on my side. Wrapped around this list is a container div, with a header and footer like most sites. The ul also uses a CSS sprite for the images, so that the normal picture is only about half the height of the image, and the bottom are the other image sprites.

For some reason the  on an iphone/ipad are not scaling correctly, in fact my  seems to repeat the background left to right, and also the height is not maintained, so you can see the other images for the sprite. If I set no-repeat on the background, only half of the container div is filled and there is this big white gap to the right of the splash section, and the bottom area with the other sprites still display.

I have tried changing the width and height of the  to be much larger, I've also tried to wrap the  in a div with the same fixed height and width. I also tried to add the '' tag when iphones/ipads are used. None of which made any difference. It seems like the unordered list just doesn't want to fill out to the container.

```
<style media="screen">
#main{
 width: 985px;
 height: 1078px;
 background: url(../images/main.jpg);
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

#main li {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 list-style: none;
}

#mainSection1 a { left: 642px; width: 193px; top: 282px; height: 18px; position: absolute; }
#mainSection1 a:hover { background: url(../images/main.jpg) -642px -1360px; }
/* ... and so forth */
</style>

<ul id="main">
   <li="mainSection1"><a href="anotherpage></a></li>
   <!-- there are 8 other list items here repeating the same -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Hope you've sorted it out by now. But if you haven't could you post a screen shot of what it is meant to look like, preferably with the different elements in different colors.

Comment: iPhone 4 scaling issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470404/enhancing-image-quality-for-iphone-4-from-72ppi-to-326ppi

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the repeating issue by adding `no-repeat` to your background declarations.

> background: url(../images/main.jpg) -642px -1360px no-repeat;

Comment: "If I set no-repeat on the background, only half of the container div is filled and there is this big white gap to the right of the splash section, and the bottom area with the other sprites still display." [sic]

Comment: Dominic, do you have a version of this live that I could look at?