# enhancing image quality for iphone 4 from 72ppi to 326ppi

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have been trying to understand how to enhance the button quality of my mobile design. My navigation buttons are currently a png sprite that is 72ppi then I have a copy of these buttons in 326 ppi. I have read that iphone4 can automatically pick up the 326ppi image by adding @x2 to the current navigation sprite? At the moment I'm just a little confused about the process and how my current navigation sprite of 194x343px @ 72ppi can change into an image 335x1469px @ 326ppi?

If anyone can provide some useful info and guidance that would be great.

Kyle

Comment: Aren't dpi needed only for printing? All electronic monitors only understand pixels values, so you should think about the pixel resolution of the image.

Comment: @Jose sorry I added dpi instead of ppi, can you help?

Comment: I think it's really the same, what you need to care about is the pixel resolution of the image, not the inches. Then I don't know if the iPhone uses the ppi value to resize the images, but seems weird to me.

Comment: It's a size-relation matter. Pixels are bigger on computer monitor so 72ppi equals one inch. But on the iPhone 4 it'll equal roughly 1/4 inch. However, the iPhone 4 screen is smaller than a computer monitor, and will render everything smaller: text, images, etc. This is really only an issue if the user zooms into the webpage. Then, at a high enough zoom, you might see pixelation, but the same situation exists for a standard monitor as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I could gather, you can create an override stylesheet targeted towards iPhone 4 using [this technique](http://thomasmaier.me/blog/2010/06/23/css-for-iphone-4-retina-display/). What you need is a @media query, and you're good to go.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* iPhone 4 styles */
}
```

Or, if you would want to link to an external stylesheet, use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="../iphone4.css" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If your button's dimensions are 194x343px on a normal display then include a file called button.png of this size in your project and link to it in Interface Builder - then you also want an image with the dimensions 388x686px (double the size) and with a filename of button@2x.png in your project. Your app will automatically use this higher resolution image when running on a retina display.